# Linq to XML query returning empty List of a class

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I want to using Linq to help make a list of movies an actor was in. I am currently trying to use this query:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reqUrl);
            var items = (from c in doc.Descendants("filmography")
                         select new Actor
                         {
                             Filmograpgy = c.Element("link").Value,

                         }).ToList<Actor>();
```

But I get an error when I  am trying to assign a value to Filmography. This query return a list with one element with a blank Filmography. How do I assign those links to a list? I have attached the value of `c`.

```
 <filmography>
   <link href="http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70213511" rel="http://schemas.netflix.com/catalog/title" title="Rock of Ages"></link>
   <link href="http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70173048" rel="http://schemas.netflix.com/catalog/title" title="Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol"></link>
   <link href="http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70127226" rel="http://schemas.netflix.com/catalog/title" title="Knight and Day"></link>
   <link href="http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70125259" rel="http://schemas.netflix.com/catalog/title" title="Together: The Hendrick Motorsports Story"></link>
</filmography>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code assumes there is a *single* link element, but there are many - also you probably don't want its value (which is empty) but e.g. the title attribute:

```
 Filmography = c.Elements("link")
                .Select(x => x.Attribute("title").Value)
                .ToList();
```

Above assumes the `Filmography` property is a `List<string>` which contains the film titles. That's the best I can do given that you don't show the class definition of `Actor` and what data you actually meant to query for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull out the [href attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387086.aspx). Value would get the value between the link tag `<link>VALUE</link>`.

You need:

```
c.Element("link").Attribute("href")
```

Also, you are only getting one value because you are performing your select based on the selection of the root node (filmography).

```
<filmography> 
    <link>THIS WILL GET PICKED IN THE ORIGINAL QUERY</link>
    <link>THIS WILL BE IGNORED</link>
    <link>THIS WILL BE IGNORED</link>
    <link>THIS WILL BE IGNORED</link>
</filmography>
```

If you want each link then you need to make your query find those elements, THEN select what you need from each one

```
c.Elements("link")
    .Select(c=>c.Attribute("href").Value)
    .ToList();
```